# logout from google plus after sharing from android application

Tags: android-studio, google-plus, logout, sharing, social-media

I am making an android application from which users can share on google plus their views about my application. First time, when i click on share button it ask to enter username and password of the user, after entering it sharing is performed successfully then after when i click again on share button it didn't ask username and password, application simply login using the old user login details. It's an application which is to be used by many user from single device. So everytime a new user uses my application he/she should be redirected to a new login page.

For sharing i am using following code :-

```
         shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Launch the Google+ share dialog with attribution to your app.
            Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(HomeActivity.this)
                    .setType("text/plain")
                    .setText("Welcome to the Google+ platform.")
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
                    .getIntent();

            startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
        }
    });
```

I have used following codes to implement the scheme but it seems that problem still persist.

```
     if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                    }
                });
   }

  private void revokeGplusAccess() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "User access revoked!");
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                        updateUI(false);
                    }

                });
    }
}
```

Is their a method other than googleplus integration for sharing from android application ?
Any help is appreciated

Regards
Ajay

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
private void signOutFromGplus() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }
```

Refer [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/) more more details.

Comment: I have updated my code and had used that link before. After sharing, user should logout from google plus and when some other user click on share button it should needs to fill the details to get going

Comment: What do you mean by "it should needs to fill the details to get going" ??

Comment: grammer error :-After sharing on google plus, user should logout from google plus and when some other user click on share button,he/she should needs to fill his/her details to share on google plus. 
I have also integrated facebook sdk in my application and in that everytime user clicks on login button he/she redirected to login page of facebook in webview.For this to happen, I have deleted facebook app from my android device

Comment: you mean credentials by details ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

First of all, declare:

```
private static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_SHARE = 10; // Or another number
```

In your "sharing" code use:

```
startActivityForResult(shareIntent, REQUEST_GOOGLE_SHARE);
```

Then, you have to manage the "logout/disconnect" in the `onActivityResult()` method. Try with the following:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {

        ...

        case REQUEST_GOOGLE_SHARE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Disconnect the user from Google
                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                    Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient);
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                }
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

In that way, you share your post calling `startActivityOnResult()` method. 
After that, the `onActivityResult()` is automatically invoked. In this method, in the `REQUEST_GOOGLE_SHARE` case, you check if the share went well, if yes you disconnect the user.